# To find $L^{-1} \circ L$ and $E \circ (L^{-1} \circ L) $

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

Let $L$ and $E$ be relations defined as

$L = \{ (s,r) \in S \times R  \mid \text{student } s \text{ lives in dorm room } r \}$

$E= \{(s,c) \in S \times C \mid \text{student } s \text{ is enrolled in course } c\}$

where $S$ is the set of students in a school, $C$ is the set of courses in a school and $R$ is the set of all dorm rooms.

I have to find out what $L^{-1} \circ L$ and $E \circ (L^{-1} \circ L)$ mean.
Now  after writing out definitions I write the answer as

1. $L^{-1} \circ L = \{(s_1,s_2) \mid \text{there is a dorm room which is shared by two students} \}$
2. $ E \circ (L^{-1} \circ L) = \{(s,c) \mid \text{there is a student who has taken a course} \\ \text{ and lives with some other student in some room} \}$

Please check if it is correct. Thanks

Comment: Surely the first should be " s_1, s_2 live in the same dorm room", and not an existential claim. Ditto for second.

Comment: Can it be said that pair of students who live in same room

Comment: You should use the same format for the new relations as is used for the ones given in the question. Your answer to (1) says it is the set of all $(s_1,s_2)$ such that .... and there's no mention of $s_1,s_2$.

Comment: Does RoS = { (x,z) : some y with (x,y) in R and (y,z) }?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes